How to think about $\sum_{b=1}^m 2b{n\choose 2b}$ (A modified version of Chairman problem)
I recently came across the following sum
$$
\sum_{b=1}^m 2b{n\choose 2b},
$$
where $n=2m$ or $n=2m+1$. I am aware of a similar sum where
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk{n\choose k} = n2^{n-1},
$$
since the right hand side is size the set: Pick a committee from $n$ people by first choosing the chairperson and then choosing rest of the $n-1$ people and the right hand side is size of the set: summation of choosing $k$ people from $n$ people to form the committee  and then choosing one of the $k$ membered committee as chairperson.
I am not sure how to adapt the later to get the former sum to be equal to a nicer expression. Can you give me some references? I am not a combinatorist and therefore I may not be aware of some nice online library of identities or some tables in textbooks.

You are missing the right-hand side in your first expression, and in the second expression I guess $m=n$. But it looks like you are asking about a special case of the Chu-Vandermonde summation formula. You could get it from the binomial theorem by expanding $(1+x)^{n-1}-(1-x)^{n-1}$ and plugging in $x=1$.

@the_village_kid Yes, I see that you edited the question. You can get such an expression by any one of the two methods I mentioned. By the way, software like Maple or Wolfram Alpha can compute your sum.

Suppose you have a committee of size $n$
We ask, how many ways can you have an evenly-sized sub-committee with a chair-person?  We count in two ways.

Break into cases based on the size of the subcommittee.  If the subcommittee was of size $2b$ we first pick the $2b$ members to serve on the subcommittee and from those members we pick a member to serve as chairperson.  This gives a total of $\sum\limits_{b=1}^\infty 2b\binom{n}{2b}$

Pick the chair-person first in $n$ ways.  Then, from all remaining people apart from the person chosen as chair-person and apart from a particular remaining person... we'll call him John Smith... choose any subset of them to serve on the sub-committee in $2^{n-2}$ ways.  If the size of the sub-committee selected was even (and so combined with the person chosen for chair would make it odd), then also include John Smith to make the final subcommittee selection even-sized.  Else, if the size was odd, do not include John Smith.  This gives a total of $n2^{n-2}$


We have as a result:
$$\sum\limits_{b=1}^\infty 2b\binom{n}{2b} = n2^{n-2}$$
